# Magnetic Dipole Moment Formula

Tags: electromagnetism

I've been looking at the formulae for magnetic dipole moments, and keep coming across something like this:

$$\mathbf{m}=\int \mathbf{r}\times\mathbf{J}dV$$

Which is something I would be perfectly happy with, if anything actually explained what $\mathbf{r}$ was. I've been told that this is the position vector of the moment, but not with respect to what - and I would assume that the origin would make a difference to the dipole moment. It would also beg the question of where the dipole moment actually is. Should the formula, to be more specific, actually say:

$$\mathbf{m}(\mathbf{r})=\int \mathbf{r}\times\left(\mathbf{J}\left(\mathbf{r'}\right)\right)d^3\mathbf{r'}$$

Basically I'm just not certain on what the $\mathbf{r}$ actually refers to. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A more explicit  formula is 
$$
{\bf m} = \int {\bf r}\times {\bf j}({\bf r})\, d^3{\bf r}
$$ 
so ${\bf r}$ is the quantity being integrated over. Consequently ${\bf m}$ is independent of ${\bf r}$. 
You might be happier if, instead, we wrote

$$
{\bf m} = \int ({\bf r}-{\bf r}_0)\times {\bf j}({\bf r})\, d^3{\bf r}
$$ 
so that ${\bf r}_0$ is the point about which  the moment is being taken. However, since ${\nabla}\cdot {\bf j}=0$ for all cases of interest, we have (by using Stokes' theorem) 
$$
\int {\bf j}({\bf r})\,d^3 {\bf r}= 0
$$
so the moment is independent of the choice of ${\bf r}_0$.

Added comment: Emilio says that the last step is not obvious, so here it is:
As ${\bf j}$ is zero outside  some volume $\Omega$ with boundary $\partial\Omega$
$$
0= \int_{\partial\Omega} j^\mu x^\nu dS^\mu=  \int_\Omega  \partial_\mu (x^\nu j^\mu)= \int x^\nu \partial_\mu j^\mu d^3x + \int (\partial_\mu x^\nu) j^\mu d^3 x.
$$
As the first term in the last equality is zero, we  have
$$
0= \int (\partial_\mu x^\nu) j^\mu d^3 x= \delta^\nu_\mu \int j^\mu d^3x = \int j^\nu d^3 x
$$

Comment: The use of Stokes' theorem here isn't obvious at all. It would be if it was a surface integral, b it that's not the case here.

Comment: Thanks! I just wasn't entirely certain. I had a hunch that it might be independent of origin, but had absolutely no idea how to prove it!

Comment: @Emilio Pisanty I'll add the derivation